# C++ CListCtrl How get cell border in View List

Tags: c++, list, border, clistctrl

I have a CListBox with a View of type List. It has only one column that the View of type List splits.

I need to draw a border around each Item .

The column contains a blank icon with size 1 and the text.

How can I draw the box ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your image invisible ? Please post something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding style [LVS_EX_GRIDLINES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774732(v=vs.85).aspx).